# Как в Kivy делать много оконные приложения без Builder'а

Tags: python, kivy

Хочу сделать программу на Kivy, с использованием нескольких окон, но мне бы желательно это сделать без Builder'а, но я никак не могу понять что нужно вписать в on_press. Я пробовал так:

1.
on_press = root.manage.current = "name"
2.     on_press = root.manager.current == "name"

Но в первом варианте выбывает `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, а во втором `NameError: name "root" is not defined`.

Вот часть кода:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class LenPasword(Screen):
    pass

program = ScreenManager()
program.add_widget(LenPasword(name = "lenpasword"))

class PaswordingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", spacing = 5, padding = [10])

        button_new_pasword = Button(text = "New Pasword",
                                    background_color = [0, 1.5, 3, 1],
                                    size_hint = [1, 0.1])

        boxlayout.add_widget(button_new_pasword)

        return boxlayout
        return program

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PaswordingApp().run()
```

Comment: `on_press = lambda: root.manage.current = "name"`? И предоставьте минимальный пример

Comment: И вы хотите по клику на кнопку поменять Screen?

Comment: Ну да, я просто не знаю почему не написал здесь on_press, но в коде он есть

Comment: А ну еще это, return program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шаги:

- Создаете окна от Screen
- В конструкторе заполняете их виджетами
- Добавляете у каждого код смены текущего экрана через `self.manager.current =`
- В классе-приложении создаете `ScreenManager`, добавляете в него ваши окна и возвращаете `ScreenManager`

Попробуйте так:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class ScreenMain(Screen):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", spacing=5, padding=[10])

        button_new_pasword = Button(
            text="New Pasword",
            background_color=[0, 1.5, 3, 1],
            size_hint=[1, 0.1],
            on_press=self._on_press_button_new_pasword,
        )

        boxlayout.add_widget(button_new_pasword)
        self.add_widget(boxlayout)

    def _on_press_button_new_pasword(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        self.manager.current = 'lenpasword'


class LenPasword(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", spacing=5, padding=[10])

        button_new_pasword = Button(
            text="Return",
            background_color=[2, 1.5, 3, 1],
            size_hint=[1, 0.1],
            on_press=self._on_press_button_new_pasword,
        )

        boxlayout.add_widget(button_new_pasword)
        self.add_widget(boxlayout)

    def _on_press_button_new_pasword(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.current = 'main_screen'


class PaswordingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ScreenMain(name='main_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(LenPasword(name='lenpasword'))

        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PaswordingApp().run()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, ещё интересует один вопрос. А как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку return, возвращала назад как вы указали, но с обратной анимацией, если можете ответе пожалуйста, а так спасибо за ваш ответ, вы и так уже помогли

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Через указание `self.manager.transition.direction`, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, хорошего дня: )